# How can I pass a string from windows.xaml to a usercontrol.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a Mainwindow.Xaml(wpf form) and 2x UserControl(EventPage.xaml and dashboard.xaml) inside this MainWindow.xaml i have a textbox and a button and i using this code to switch between my forms(EventPage.Xaml and Dashboard.Xaml) inside this Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="myContainer">
                    <Local:EventPage x:Name="eventpage" Visibility="Collapsed"></Local:EventPage>
                    <Local:Dashboard x:Name="dashboard" Visibility="Collapsed"></Local:Dashboard>       
                </Grid>
```

now i wanna pass my textbox.text to my Dashboard.Xaml with this code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public string Searchtext;


       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();


       }
private void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Searchtext = txtSearch.Text;
           Dashboard dashPage = new Dashboard(Searchtext);
       }
```

and in my usercontrol.xaml(Dashboard.Xaml) i have this code to recive my Searchtext :

```
public partial class Dashboard : UserControl
   {
       string searchtxt;

       public Dashboard(string searchtext)
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           searchtxt = searchtext;
       }
```

but i getting this error from Mainwindows.xaml in this line:

```
<Local:Dashboard x:Name="dashboard" Visibility="Collapsed"></Local:Dashboard>
```

first Error: Type 'Dashboard' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.
second Error: the type 'Dashboard' cannot have a Name attribute.Value types without a default constructor can be used as items within a ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Ok. There's a few things to break down here.

1.
Your MainWindow.xaml indicates to the program which UI classes to intialise in order to create the UI and for every element that is in the .xaml, the class that it is from will be initialised

This means that

```xml
<Local:Dashboard x:Name="dashboard" Visibility="Collapsed"></Local:Dashboard>
```

Will run this code at the background at runtime:

```
Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
dashboard.Name = "dashboard";
dashboard.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

That means that you DO NOT need:
`Dashboard dashPage = new Dashboard(Searchtext);`
in your MainWindow.xaml.cs because the Dashboard has already been created when the UI was loaded.

2.
The second problem is that you have put a parameter inside the only constructor of the Dashboard class
`Dashboard(string searchtext)`

This means that when program tries to create the UI from the MainWindow.xaml it is not able to because it tries to call
new Dashboard();
but that is not possible because you have a parameter.

Basically if you have parameters in the constructor of Dashboard such as Dashboard(string searchtext)
then the program won't be able to load a Local:Dashboard element in the UI because the UI CAN NOT set the `string searchtext`.

This is why you get the error "does not define a public parameterless constructor..."

For the second error, ensure that in your ui you only set x:Name

### Solution

Use the **dashboard** variable that the compiler creates from the UI to set the variable in the Dashboard.xaml.cs class.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Grid x:Name="myContainer">
                    <Local:EventPage x:Name="eventpage" Visibility="Collapsed"></Local:EventPage>
                    <Local:Dashboard x:Name="dashboard" Visibility="Collapsed"></Local:Dashboard>       
                </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
private void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           dashboard.searchtxt = txtSearch.Text;
       }
```

You also need to make the string in Dashboard.xaml.cs public and remove the parameter from the constructor:

```
public partial class Dashboard : UserControl
   {
       public string searchtxt;

       public Dashboard()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
```